# GPO to remapp desktop folder and user profile

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy

We moved away from roaming profiles on a windows 2008 domain, when we moved to windows 7.  We used a user policy to map the desktop folder, and the mydocument folder to a users share on a file server.

This works well for the desktops, but when a user checks out a laptop to take offsite, they then cannot use the laptop because it cannot create the desktop folder, or contact the domain.

The work around we currently have is to use a local user account on the laptop so the user can get online and either go to the internet, or VPN in to their work machine.

I'd like to know if there is a way to do this with a machine GPO, or other method, so the user doesn't get stranded when they're offsite.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you linked the GPO in at the site level and made sure all your internal IP ranges were associated with the AD site, the GPO will only apply when the user logs in at the office. When they login remotely, the GPO will not apply.

The other thing you can do it create a WMI filter that queries for an IP address that is in your range of locally connected machines and apply it to the GPO. If that succeeds the GPO will apply. If not, it will not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired results using offline folders rather than redirected folders. The users then have their data on the server for backup and other purposes and still have the local copy when required. It's certainly working well with our laptop users.